# Method getting string from ComboBox

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I have been trying to run a condiotional statement on a string I get from a ComboBox. The issue seems to be getting the string from the ComboBox, but I am not sure.

I have just been introduced to using methods for my course but it has not covered the topic properly. I have tried searching and trying different ways to return the string to a variable. It hasn't worked. I have tried debugging and the variable selectedItem does not change. I have tried a few things which my code reflects.

```
private double calcVehicleWarranty(double vehiclePrice)
        {
            const double VEHIC_WARR_1 = 0;
            const double VEHIC_WARR_2 = .05;
            const double VEHIC_WARR_3 = .10;
            const double VEHIC_WARR_4 = .20;
            string selectedItem = this.warrantyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            double warranty = 0;

            //Tried This method
            if (warrantyComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1 Year - No Charge")
            {
                warranty = VEHIC_WARR_1;
            }
            else if (warrantyComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "2 Years - 5% of Vehicle")
            {
                warranty = VEHIC_WARR_2 * vehiclePrice;
            }
            // And having a selectedItem variable
            else if (selectedItem == "3 Years - 10% of Vehicle")
            {
                warranty = VEHIC_WARR_3 * vehiclePrice;
            }
            else if (selectedItem == "5 Years - 20% of Vehicle")
            {
                warranty = VEHIC_WARR_4 * vehiclePrice;
            }
            return warranty;
        }
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="warrantyComboBox" Width="240" Margin="20" PlaceholderText="Select Vehicle Warranty">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="1 Year - No Charge" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="2 Years - 5% of Vehicle" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="3 Years - 10% of Vehicle" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="5 Years - 20% of Vehicle" />
```

The function is called with:

```
warranty = calcVehicleWarranty(vehiclePrice);
```

I expect to calculate warranty given the selection from the combobox in the easiest to understand way for a beginner

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow! might be more helpful if you also post your XAML, also, how are you calling calcVehicleWarranty?

Comment: Thanks Mac, I have updated the post with the xaml and the method call.

Comment: @Louiee - You should rarely have to call `ToString()` to get a `string` value from an object. It's mostly used to format numeric values as a `string` or to get diagnostic values. In general, calling `ToString()` to get something that is already a `string` is probably wrong.

Comment: Hi @Louiee, I understand that you're a beginner, what you can do with your existing code is change the line to this -> string selectedItem = this.warrantyComboBox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString(); SelectionBoxItem gets the item selected when the comboBox is closed, then you can use selectedItem variable in all your conditions. But keep studying, there's better ways, you'll improve.

Comment: Thankyou very much, that was what I was looking to do. I havn't really learnt the  syntax properly yet. Could you give me a hint about where I can learn more about this type of syntax? As in things like this.comboBox.SelectionBoxItem. For my project I think I will now use a switch statement as it seems like the better option.

Comment: @Louiee Try to explore `SelectionChanged` event of `ComboBox` control. You can easily get selected item there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/combo-box    and  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/step-by-step-creation-of-combo-box-control-in-universal-window-app/

Answer (score 0):

In general doing string comparisons on operations where the elements may be unknown or long strings is bad practise. A way to avoid this would be grabbing the SelectedIndex property on the combobox, this may eliminate some human error.

It may look something like this:

```
switch(warrantyComboBox.SelectedIndex)
{
   case 0:
      warranty = VEHIC_WARR_1;
      break;
   case 1:
      warranty = VEHIC_WARR_2 * vehiclePrice;
      break;
}
```

Alternatively, you should try putting a breakpoint in your code to figure out what the string looks like, then copy that into your if statement.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Using this technique how then would I assign each case to a selection from my ComboBox?

Comment: Each case you define can correlate to an element in your combo box, so as an example "case 0" would be your first element, "case 1" your second, and so on. Then all you need to do is assign your variable within each case as shown in the example. Using this method you will no longer need a huge segment filled with if and else if statements. Refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch for info on switch statements.

Comment: Thankyou, I appreciate your response, I had covered switch statements but wasn't sure how to implement it using SelectedIndex. I can appreciate how this rules out human error. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get `ComboBoxItem` content, if you use `string selectedItem = this.warrantyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();`. Because the item's type is `ComboBoxItem` not a data model. For get the content you could use the following code.

```
var selectitem = warrantyComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
var selectitemcontent = selectitem.Content.ToString();
```

> I had covered switch statements but wasn't sure how to implement it using SelectedIndex.

Please note the first index value is 0.

```
private double CalcVehicleWarranty(double vehiclePrice)
{
    const double VEHIC_WARR_1 = 0;
    const double VEHIC_WARR_2 = .05;
    const double VEHIC_WARR_3 = .10;
    const double VEHIC_WARR_4 = .20;
    double warranty = 0;

    switch (warrantyComboBox.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            warranty = VEHIC_WARR_1;
            break;
        case 1:
            warranty = VEHIC_WARR_2 * vehiclePrice;
            break;
        case 2:
            warranty = VEHIC_WARR_3 * vehiclePrice;
            break;
        case 3:
            warranty = VEHIC_WARR_4 * vehiclePrice;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }       
    return warranty;
}
```